# Crontab entry is not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, crontab

I want a set of files copied daily from a remote server to local machine at 5 am in the morning. The following crontab entry does not work:

```
   0 5 * * * scp user1@192.168.5.54:/tmp/bkp*tar.gz /home/user1/dir1
```

This is on Ubuntu 18.04 (if it matters which I don't think it should).
The command works when executed manually by the same user in whose crontab this entry is made.

Comment: When executed manually, how is the password being entered?

Comment: When you say 'it works manually', does that mean that your public/private key set-up works? For `user1`? In which crontab is this line; is that the same user as the manual execution?

Comment: @LjmDullaart  I think you have got me thinking about the problem. The user is the same, manually or in crontab. Does it have to do with not getting the public/private key set-up when run through crontab? Any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set-up public/private key authentication. `scp` needs some form of authentication on the server where you copy the files from. If you want to set-up cronjobs for `scp`, this should be passwordless keys. You are not at the terminal to type the password for your cronjob.

There is a utility called `sshpass` that allows you to script the password, without setting-up pub/priv keys. It is not always available, and is perhaps a lesser solution.

If you worry about security (or if this is not a home-solution), create a separate user for the file transfer and make sure that that user has only authorizations that are required for the copying.

Note that `ssh-agent` will not help you in this case.

Comment: I am using public/private key authentication. I understand that cron runs differently than when I am manually scp-ing.

Comment: If you want to set-up cronjobs for scp, this should be *passwordless* keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using keys, the `ssh-agent` helper is not run because `cron` is not going through the standard login process.

You'll need to start `ssh-agent` manually.  For more information see for example https://www.ssh.com/ssh/agent

Comment: Will look into issues related to ssh-agent...